# Skip first record in loop in first iteration only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create an each loop that will skip the first record on the first loop but then show it on the second iteration. Is this possible?

I know that the following would start at the second item in the array but obviously it would still skip the first record on it's second loop around.

```
    <% @example[1..n].each do |example| %>
      ...
    <% end %>
```

**EDIT:** To give a bit of context - this is my code currently. I don't really know javascript too well and I'm probably doing this in a more complicated way than it needs to be.

Also could people please explain why this is a bad question when giving negative votes. I'm trying to learn from scratch. I don't know anyone who codes so I can't bounce ideas from someone so it would be nice for people to tell me if I've misunderstood the concept as I don't learn anything from a negative vote without any kind of reasoning.

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8  no-gutters">
<div class="divs">
    <% @example.each do |example| %>
        <!--example information goes here -->
    <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4  no-gutters">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-md-12 no-gutters" style="position: relative; text-align: center; color: white;">
            <div class="divs2">
                <% @example.each do |example| %>
                    <!--this is the one I want to skip the first item on-->
                <% end %>   
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 no-gutters">
            <div class="container text-center">     
                <span>
                    <a id="prev" class="hidden"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a id="next"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

```
$('a#next').click(function(){
$('a#prev').removeClass('hidden');
    });

 $(document).ready(function(){
$(".divs div").each(function(e) {
    if (e != 0)
        $(this).hide();
});

$("#next").click(function(){
    if ($(".divs div:visible").next().length != 0)
        $(".divs div:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
    else {
        $(".divs div:visible").hide();
        $(".divs div:first").show();
    }
    return false;
});

$("#prev").click(function(){
    if ($(".divs div:visible").prev().length != 0)
        $(".divs div:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
    else {
        $(".divs div:visible").hide();
        $(".divs div:last").show();
    }
    return false;
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".divs2 div").each(function(e) {
    if (e != 0)
        $(this).hide();
});

$("#next").click(function(){
    if ($(".divs2 div:visible").next().length != 0)
        $(".divs2 div:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
    else {
        $(".divs2 div:visible").hide();
        $(".divs2 div:first").show();
    }
    return false;
});

$("#prev").click(function(){
    if ($(".divs2 div:visible").prev().length != 0)
        $(".divs2 div:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
    else {
        $(".divs2 div:visible").hide();
        $(".divs2 div:last").show();
    }
    return false;
}); });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "then show it on the second iteration"?

Comment: When the loop goes back to the beginning - I want it to show the first record that it skipped initially.  E.g. [1, 2, 3] - I want it to skip 1 on the first go so we get [2, 3]. But then on the second iteration I would like it to show [1,2,3]. As I'm using a next button to show hidden divs but I need to skip the first div initially.

Comment: Why do you think loop will go back to beginning? Not unless you are using nested loops.

Comment: Sorry I'm probably out of my depth explaining things as I'm a bit of an amateur. I'm not really sure what a nested loop is. I'll add a link to my code in the main image in the next few minutes to try and show what I've got.

Comment: Nested loop is loop inside loop. Check https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_nested_loops.htm if you are curious.

Comment: Thank you. I'll have a read of this later. :)

Answer (score 12):

Use the `drop` method.

```
@example.drop(1).each do |item|
...
end
```

Afterwards use the normal `each`

```
@example.each do |item|
...
end
```

[Documentation](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html)